# Size limits on stringstream for embedded

Tags: c++11, stm32, stringstream

Keen to use `stringstream` on an STM32 for handling data that gets sent over various UART connections to radio modules (wifi, BLE, Zigbee, etc). I am running FreeRTOS, if that matters.
Very concerned about the dynamic memory allocation in the STL lib causing unhandled overflows (I have to have "-fno-exceptions").
I can handle buffer overruns myself in a simple writer method, so that isn't an issue, but I want to be certain that the `stringstream` never tries to increase it's memory beyond a pre-set limit.

Currently I just use `char*` buffers, but, I want to find a better solution.

I want to be able to do something like this.

```
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

class Wifi
{
public:
    std::stringstream* ss;

    Wifi()
    {
        ss.set_max_size(1024); // 1kB
    }
};
```

TIA

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22025719/10927863) answer can help

Comment: Yes smashing. That means I can use the reserve() method. Much appreciated. Feel free to put as an answer so I can give you the proper credit. Cheers

Comment: Turns out that doesn't work in that you don't have access to the underlying string so you can't use the capacity() method, nor the shrink_to_fit() method. :-(

Comment: Basic stringstreams have an allocator template argument. You could try making an allocator that never allocates beyond a boundary, but if I read the [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) correctly, it relies on exceptions to communicate errors.

Comment: I also wanted a better, more modern solution. I've been developing for embedded devices for ...a while and always avoided heavy string and streams. Recently came across 
Stroustrup's "convert an integer to a string" advice: www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#int-to-string so I tried just adding `std::stringstream ss;` line into the code and linker told me `region 'FLASH' overflowed by 77328 bytes` (with STM32CubeIDE defaults) ... code size went from 69kB to 203kB... on a 128kB flash controller... NO thanks! Nice Zero-overhead principle guys. Good luck to you. I will keep avoiding sstream header.

Comment: The zero overhead principle is incredibly misleading because it is correct for the language but many libraries are incredibly heavy on flash memory. Maybe modules might help but I'm not holding my breath for a "from X import y" type python solution, so you only get what you need